# Linking ArcGIS Map to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: arcgis-desktop, excel, arcgis-10.4

Is it possible to have a workable ArcGIS map within Excel?

Reason:  We are generating a request form for fire flows.  When a request comes in we need to identify exactly which hydrant(s) will be tested.  It would be simplest if within the Excel request form we could embed our ArcGIS map which has our cities fire hydrant locations, instead of having to open ArcGIS separately, snip the portion of the map, and copy it into Excel for the team responsible for the fire flow testing.

I know this isn't very technical, but I was looking for a tutorial, or for someone to point me in the right direction so I could set this up.

Comment: I'd use Python script that pan to hydrant of interest and exports picture to fixed image control. Can be done without opening of the map

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ESRI Maps for Office. There you are able to log into whatever ArcGIS Online/Portal environment you choose, and embed a map and/or do some analysis.